# Search data.frame by row with multiple factors

Tags: r, filter, dataframe, split

I couldn't find another question that would answer this one so here it is :

I have a `data.frame` (lets say `nodes`) in which are stored nodes attributes, one column is the node's ID and all other columns are the node's attributes.
I have a second `data.frame` (lets says `def`) where combinations of my nodes attributes are matched to a value.

What I am trying to do is add a new column/attribute to `nodes` so that combinations of `nodes` `data.frame` are matched to the values defined in `def`.

It basically would look like that

```
> nodes
Attr1 Attr2 Attr3
1     1     1
2     1     2
1     3     1
3     2     1
```

and

```
> def
Attr1 Attr3 Res
1     1     1
1     2     2
2     1     3
2     2     4
```

And should return

```
> nodes
Attr1 Attr2 Attr3 Res
1     1     1     1
2     1     2     4
1     3     1     1
1     2     1     2
```

For now, I am thinking of using `split` to subset my `data.frame` into multiple `data.frames`each corresponding to a combinations of my factors of interest and then giving to the proper rows the proper values but I have some problem with that method :

- If there are lots attributes `split` is gonna take a real long time
- How would I put my `data.frame` back in one piece ?
- It does not sound elegant at all

So is there another way to do that ? And if not how would I build back my data.frame ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to do a join?  Would this work ?  `dplyr::left_join(nodes,def,by = c("Attr1", "Attr3"))`

Comment: Looks like it is exactly that, thanks for the answer and sorry for the duplicate.